# Can a stock belong to multiple "tapes"?

Tags: equities

My question is about the dissemination of price and quote information by the CTA and UTP  (Consolidated Tape Association https://www.ctaplan.com/index , UTP https://www.utpplan.com/). I know that NYSE listed stocks are tape A, NASD listed stocks are tape C, and the rest are tape B. But a stock can be listed on multiple exchanges, so can the same stock be on multiple tapes? Or does it go by primary listing? If so, how is the primary listing of a stock determined when it's listed on multiple exchanges?

Answer (score 2):

A stock is listed on only one exchange, the others just trade it also.